DXTools BasePlugin
I have an assembly called dxtools.basesolutions.plugins. Assembly has one step called PreValidateNoteCreate.
Since this is a 3rd party plugin, I can not find any code or reference on my Repos. I can only see this through Registration Tool.
I am on 8.2 version(On-Prem) and want to migrate to cloud. I want to know what is this plugin doing exactly with the Notes entity and If i can replace this part through sandbox plugins.
Anyone worked on something similar?
See the Image here
Checked all the repos, tried to profile the plugin and run trigger the action to get logs but no luck.

You can download the plugin assembly. E.g. use the Assembly Recovery Tool plugin in the XrmToolBox.
Then disassemble the plugin. For Visual Studio ILSpy is a nice plugin.
